# HMI macro of if-else statement

Tags: if-statement, button, automation, plc

I want to use buttons in HMI screen to control the plc. The result should be when I turn on one of the button and another one will be turned off. What should I type in the screen cycle macro in order to make the function work?

[Buttons in HMI and screen for macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMYch.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify the model or brand of the HMI, and I couldn't identify it from the image and the code doesn't seem to be standardized as ST from IEC-61131, I'll put it as a "pseudo-code", so you'll have to adjust it according to the correct syntax.

```
//Declare as global or equivalent, or use a PLC memory
Bool oldM3
Bool oldM4

//------- Run cycllic --------

//Get the transition of M3
IF NOT oldM3 AND M3 THEN
    oldM3 = true
    M4 = false
ENDIF

IF NOT M3 THEN
    oldM3 = false
ENDIF

//Get the transition of M4
IF NOT oldM4 AND M4 THEN
    oldM4 = true
    M3 = false
ENDIF

IF NOT M4 THEN
    oldM4 = false
ENDIF
```